# Are there PL-exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$s?

Tags: geometric-topology

The title may or may not say it all. I know that there are examples of topological 4-manifolds with nonequivalent PL structures. In some [lecture notes](http://www-math.mit.edu/~lurie/937notes/937Lecture3.pdf), Jacob Lurie mentions that not every PL manifold is smoothable, and that while smoothings exist in dimension 7 they may not be unique, as the existence of exotic $S^7$s shows when combined with the PL Poincar`e conjecture in dimensions other than $4$.

This phrasing suggests that *smoothings of PL manifolds are unique in dimensions 1 through 6,* which would mean that from the continuum of exotic smooth $\mathbb{R}^4$s we'd get a continuum of exotic PL $\mathbb{R}^4$s. But I haven't yet found a reference for the italicized fact-is it true, or is Lurie's phrasing imprecise, and if it's false, are there even so some exotic PL $\mathbb{R}^4$s?

Comment: The italicized fact is claimed in Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-manifold#Smooth_4-manifolds). The reference is an AMS article by Milnor (http://www.ams.org/notices/201106/rtx110600804p.pdf).

Comment: Ah, great, thanks!

Comment: The proof is in the book of Kirby and Siebenmann "Foundational essays on topological manifolds ...", which is, sadly, unreadable.

Comment: Great, thanks for the reference. I suppose I will then go ahead and...not read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this](http://www.ams.org/notices/201106/rtx110600804p.pdf) survey article on differential topology, Milnor outlines a proof that every PL manifold of dimension $n \leq 7$ possesses a compatible differential structure, and whenever $n<7$ this structure is unique up to isomorphism. He includes references for the various facts he uses.